# Python Simple-Salesforce change 'concurrencyMode'

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm utilizing Python's simple-salesforce package to execute a bulk upload. I'm seeing some inconsistent response errors that I believe can be resolved by changing the    'concurrencyMode' to 'Serial'

I don't see that option in the documentation. Does anyone know if it's possible to update the source code to add that parameter to a request? I tried updating the headers in api.py and bulk.py with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simple-salesforce` bulk methods are using Salesforce [Bulk API 1.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_jobs_create.htm) by POSTing to `https://<salesforce_instance>/services/async/<api_version>/job`. In [`bulk.py`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/bulk.py), the job is created like so:

```
 def _create_job(self, operation, object_name, external_id_field=None):
        """ Create a bulk job
        Arguments:
        * operation -- Bulk operation to be performed by job
        * object_name -- SF object
        * external_id_field -- unique identifier field for upsert operations
        """

        payload = {
            'operation': operation,
            'object': object_name,
            'contentType': 'JSON'
        }
```

This generates the following XML payload:

```
<jobInfo
   xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
 <operation>...</operation>
 <object>...</object>
 <contentType>JSON</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

To explicitly request a serial job, you need to add `concurrencyMode` element to the request. The `jobInfo` fragment should be

```
<jobInfo
   xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
 <operation>...</operation>
 <object>...</object>
 <concurrencyMode>Serial</concurrencyMode>
 <contentType>JSON</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

Change the `_create_job` to have this extra element:

```
 def _create_job(self, operation, object_name, external_id_field=None):
        """ Create a serial bulk job
        Arguments:
        * operation -- Bulk operation to be performed by job
        * object_name -- SF object
        * external_id_field -- unique identifier field for upsert operations
        """

        payload = {
            'operation': operation,
            'object': object_name,
            'concurrencyMode': 'Serial',
            'contentType': 'JSON'
        }
```